# Could not convert value int to type System.String for property Id in IDbMapper reader object

Tags: c#

I have a IDataReader reader object and using this when i try to fetch next result like below:

```
private readonly IDbMapper<Items> _dbMapperItems;
List<Items> types= new();
 
public class Items
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

if (reader.NextResult())
{
    types = _dbMapperItems.Map(reader).ToList();
}
```

My database returning int value for Id field present in types class but in c# side the Id variable of types class is string, and because of that i am getting error saying "Could not convert value 10001 to type System.String for property Id" so how can i convert this in above mapper to string.

Comment: is this possible to change the `Id` to `int` in `Items` class?

Comment: @viveknuna Apart from this int value there are several other string values are also getting mapped using that class so can't change that one.

Comment: what is your `IDbMapper` class and its Map method? Is it your custom class ?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran That's a custom class but we dont have access to it. I have to do the changes via above piece of code only.

Comment: Then you are pretty much stuck. If you have access to change the sql query, you could apply `cast` function for each of the int column to return them as varchar type.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran yes i have the sql query access, added cast statement for converting int to string and it starts working. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify your SQL query to use the `cast` function for each of the integer columns to return it as `varchar`, then the custom data reader will be able to convert to your `Items` class.